# How to change Jetstream logo in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I installed Laravel 8 with Jetstream authentication. Now I want to change the login components, specifically the logo. Where are these components placed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this, follow below step.

You can run below commands to publish the assets.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views
```

After that files will be available under the folder `resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components`

Answer (score 6):

There is an answer in the installation tutorial.

https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/installation.html#application-logo

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views
```

**Livewire**

> Next, you should customize the SVGs located in the resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components/application-logo.blade.php, resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components/authentication-card-logo.blade.php, and resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components/application-mark.blade.php components.

**Inertia**

> Next, you should customize the SVGs located in resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components/authentication-card-logo.blade.php, resources/js/Jetstream/ApplicationLogo.vue, and resources/js/Jetstream/ApplicationMark.vue. After customizing these components, you should rebuild your assets:

Comment: What if i want to change it to a .png ?

Answer (score 4):

**Just add your own html.**

Do like this,

```
<x-slot name="logo">
    <img src="{{ url('logo.png') }}" />
</x-slot>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get your logo on your database.

You need to run first `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views` this command. After that, you need to get `resources\views\auth\login.blade.php` and replace this `<x-jet-authentication-card-logo />` with you own component!

You can do this like that run this command `php artisan make:component AppLogo` And create a your own component.

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use App\Models\GeneralSettings;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class AppLogo extends Component
{
    public $logo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->logo = GeneralSettings::first()->favicon;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.home.app-logo');
    }
}
```

After that you need to edit your `resources\views\components\home\app-logo.blade.php` file like that;

```
<div>
    <img src="{{$logo}}">
</div>
```

After that, you need to get `resources\views\auth\login.blade.php` and replace this `<x-jet-authentication-card-logo />` with you own component! Like that `<x-applogo />`

Result to be like that;

```
<x-guest-layout>
    <x-jet-authentication-card>
        <x-slot name="logo">
{{--            <x-jet-authentication-card-logo />--}}
            <x-applogo />
        </x-slot>

        <x-jet-validation-errors class="mb-4" />
....
```

Answer (score 2):

**To change Jetstream logo in Laravel 8**.
You must do 3 steps

- 1.first run This Command to generate components
  **php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views**   this will generate view     [\vendor\laravel\jetstream\resources\views] To
  [\resources\views\vendor\jetstream]
- 2.Open \resources\views\vendor\jetstream and move to  authentication-card-logo.blade
- 3.Crate your Svg image from [https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHVpq.png) or download
  free from [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHVpq.png): https://freesvg.org I also change my logo by doing
  this [image: this the login page of jetstreme]

Answer (score 0):

On Laravel 10, to change Jetstream Logo on all pages:

1. Replace content of **/resources/views/components/application-logo.blade.php** by:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" alt=""/>
```

2. Replace content of **/resources/views/components/authentication-card-logo.blade.php** by:

```
<a href="/">
    <img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" alt=""/>
</a>
```